# Windows BAT Script to delete sub-folder in directory

Tags: batch-file

My folder structure as follows

```
E:\test1\42\5440001\5338023\html
E:\test1\43\5440021\5338024\html
E:\test1\47\5440021\5638024\html
E:\test1\43\5448721\5339024\html
```

and so on...

Wherein HTML folder, **ABC** named sub-folder (common name in all folders) requires to delete.

Can any body help me on this by providing BAT script to delete all **ABC** sub folders in single shot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "E:\test1"
FOR /D /R %%A IN (*ABC) DO RMDIR /S /Q %%A
```

Before you actually run the above script to delete the folders, you can confirm you'll be deleting the right ones with this script.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "E:\test1"
FOR /D /R %%A IN (*ABC) DO ECHO %%A
```

I'd highly recommend running the second script first just to make sure you only get the folders you want.